# Заменить спрайт у дочернего объекта в Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Всем привет. Есть задача, сделать кнопку с картинкой и чтобы при наведении на эту кнопку менялась картинка.

В голову пришло только одно решение:

- Создал кнопку ( Button )
- Создал картинку ( Image ) как дочерний объект в Button
- При наведении на кнопку навесил событие.

И вся проблема заключается в том, чтобы у дочернего объекта поменять спрайт. Пытаюсь поменять спрайт следующим образом:

```
if (this.transform.Find ("Image")) {
   Debug.Log ("OnHover");
   Image bImg = this.GetComponent<Image>();
   bImg.sprite = ButtonImageHover;
}
```

Но почему то спрайт не меняется, хотя в консоли при наведении на кнопку пробегает "OnHover" ...

Comment: Контекст утрачен. Пробуй так:  Image bImg = this.transform.Find ("Image").GetComponent<Image>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VeryBadUser, тогда я бы сделал иначе.

операция **Find** может уменьшить производительность. А еще могут быть проблемы если на сцене несколько объектов по имени "Image". И тогда не факт что это будет дочерний объект.

> GameObject.Find is useful for automatically connecting references to other objects at load time; for example, inside MonoBehaviour.Awake or
>   MonoBehaviour.Start.
>   For performance reasons, it is recommended to not use this function
>   every frame.
>   A common pattern is to assign a GameObject to a variable inside
>   MonoBehaviour.Start, and use the variable in MonoBehaviour.Update.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
       public Image bImg;// Можно назначить через инспектор.
       void Awake()
       {
           bImg = transform.Find("/Image").GetComponent<Image>();// Или найти среди дочерних объектов. 
       }

       void F()
       {
          if (bImg  != null) {
            Debug.Log ("OnHover");     
            bImg.sprite = ButtonImageHover; 
            }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Такие вещи можно делать двумя способами без всякого кода:

1. Через анимацию состояния кнопок, вы можете настроить смену состояния
   нескольких объектов по вашему желанию ([официальный туториал где то
   с 5:30 про анимацию кнопки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ZNuM6K27E)).
2. Добавляете на кнопку `EventTrigger` и на него добавляете обработку
   событий под указателем (`PointerEnter`) и указатель
   ушел(`PointerExit`)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем меньше кода, тем гибче будет возможность настройки ваших кнопок)

Comment: Первоначально, я решил делать всё через код, т.к. на экране порядка 15 кнопок ( с настройками, режимы игры, вперед, назад и т.п. ) и я хотел упросить их настройку, но в итоге всё равно на каждую кнопку приходится кидать по минимум 2 спрайта, но всё равно быстрей, если задавать на каждую тригеры ))) ( за совет, плюсег ))

Answer (score 1):

Это делается вообще без кода.

Используй элемент Button и выставь все что нужно в настройках инспектора

Comment: да, вариант не плохой, но там уже всё занято (т.е. у меня кнопка уже задействует несколько спрайтов ( кнопка в нормальном состоянии - 1 спрайт, кнопка при наведении - 2 спрайт ). Т.е. по сути дела, я хочу заменить текст кнопки на картинку.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Valera Kvip. Воспользовался вашим решением:

```
if (this.transform.Find ("Image")) {
   Debug.Log ("OnHover");   
   Image bImg = this.transform.Find ("Image").GetComponent<Image>();
   bImg.sprite = ButtonImageHover; 
}
```